# Удаление из массива информацию

Tags: javascript, массивы, arraylist

Имеется такой массив:

```
var lpeers = [ { id: 'id2' }, { id: 'id3' }];
lpeers["id2"] = { uid: '1', apiId: '1', iddb: 30, ip: '127.0.0.1' };
lpeers["id3"] = { uid: '1', apiId: '1', iddb: 31, ip: '127.0.0.1' };
```

как из него удалить lpeers["id2"] ?

```
Array.prototype.exterminate2 = function (value) {
  for (var i=this.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
      if (this[i].id === value) {
          this.splice(i, 1);
          break;       //<-- Uncomment  if only the first term has to be removed
      }
  }
}

lpeers.exterminate2("id2");
```

данный код затронет только эту часть:

```
[ { id: 'id2' }, { id: 'id3' }];
```

в результате получится:

```
[ { id: 'id3' }];
```

а эта часть не изменится:

```
lpeers["id2"] = { uid: '1', apiId: '1', iddb: 30, ip: '127.0.0.1' };
lpeers["id3"] = { uid: '1', apiId: '1', iddb: 31, ip: '127.0.0.1' };
```

Вернусь к вопросу как удалить lpeers["id2"] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хочу Вас предупредить, что использовать массив как объект - плохо

```
var removeID = 'id2';

Object.keys(lpeers).forEach(function(key) { 
  if (key === removeID || lpeers[key].id === removeID) {
    delete lpeers[key];
  }
});
```